# Device Toolbar - Responsive View

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, responsive

*Version 65.0.3325.146 (Official Build) (64-bit)*

---

Going into responsive mode seems to keep desktop view and crop the screen.

All of the preset phone dimensions don't work, but a custom one seems to fix it.

Is this a bug or is there a resolution?

Video of issue: https://streamable.com/oe5in

Answer (score 0):

Same here. Setting the size manually worked (like, creating a new device with the same size as another prebuilt one), but its not really optimal. I wonder if this has something to do with device pixel density.

But it should not happen at responsive mode. :(

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's an official bug, issue has been reported to Google here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=819489#c47